# Why GraphicsContext uses methods with double params?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, int, double

I'm moving from swing to javafx. I wondered why GraphicsContext uses methods with double params. For example `fillRect(double x, double y, double w, double h)` unlike swing has methods `drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)`.

Should I do all my calculations in double?

Comment: The original Graphics class was focused on the screen, Graphics2D was designed to work with much higher precision  output, like printers (and where talking commercial printers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drawRect` in inherited from `Graphics` which uses `int` to specify the co-ords & size.

The `Graphics2D` object on the other hand, is capable of dealing with graphics values that lie 'between whole pixels'.  To compensate it will typically render a dithered pixel (part way between the drawing and BG color) at parts of the rendering where it has to deal with fractions of a pixel.

> Should I do all my calculations in double?

Yes!  Double values that are exactly equal to an integer will be rendered as you might expect from the `Graphics` method - with sharp, clean lines.  But if the boundary of the shape ever falls between whole pixels, the color will be dithered.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. So if I need to paint some objects with clear borders, I should use int params, in other case double

Comment: *"So if I need to paint some objects with clear borders, I should use int params"*  I wouldn't say it's that simple.  For instance, instead of a square, where every edge is exactly vertical or horizontal, think of a diamond shape.  It would not matter if each of the points of the diamond are at integer values, most of the values in between one point and the next are not.  So the graphics object has to make a choice between drawing a jagged line, or pixel dithering anyway.   But the simplest answer is:- **using doubles will produce a better drawing.**